# Interstitial dfp ads not filling full screen on Android tablets

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial, google-dfp

We are attempting to serve full page ads via DFP and AdMob to our Android app. We cannot get ads to fill the screen, ads will only appear in the predefined interstitial sizes, 320x480 for the 7inch device and 768x1024 for the 10inch device. How do we get the DFP SDK to accurately detect the device screen resolution and scale the ad to fill the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an OutOfPage creative. In this kind of creative you don't need to specify a size and these are designed for stickies and interstitials.

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6088046?hl=en